# apk updates size on PlayStore

Tags: android, apk, developer-console

My app is about 25Mb and when I upload an update my users are forced to download 25mb every time.
I noticed that when downloading many other applications updates, the download file is much lighter than the total weight of the application (eg 5Mb instead of 30Mb).
I'm not able to do it from the developer console, what should I do to achieve this? I search a lot but I didn't find anything

Comment: For the other applications, are you comparing their size on disk with the size of the APK when they are updated? If so, the apk will always be smaller than the size of the app on disk. There currently isn't, and I doubt there will ever be a patch mechanism as for it to work it would probably either require the device to de-compile the current version of the app to splice in the patch and then re-compile it. Other options for this working are also fairly complex..

Comment: I've seen update with the size of few kb, while the entire app size is more than 50MB. So i Think that there is a way to do it.

Go to your "updates" tab on the play store and you'll see I'm right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic